# Python - Pandas Data manipulation to calculate Gini Coefficient

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am having dataset which is of the following shape:

```
tconst  GreaterEuropean British WestEuropean    Italian French  Jewish  Germanic    Nordic  Asian   GreaterEastAsian    Japanese    Hispanic    GreaterAfrican  Africans    EastAsian   Muslim  IndianSubContinent  total_ethnicities
0   tt0000001   3   1   2   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8
1   tt0000002   2   0   2   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6
2   tt0000003   4   0   3   0   3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11
3   tt0000004   2   0   2   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6
4   tt0000005   3   2   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7
```

It is IMDB data and after processing, I created these columns which represents there are this many number of ethnic actors in a movie (tcons).

I want to create another column `df["diversity"]` which is:

`( diversity score "gini index")`

For example:
for each movie lets say we have 10 actors; 3 asian, 3 British, 3 african american and 1 french. so we divide by total
3/10     3/ 10   3/10     1/10
then     1  minus the summation of (  3/10 ) square   ( 3/ 10) square  ( 3/10) square (1/10) square 
add the score of each actor to a column as diversity.

I am trying simple pandas manipulation, but not getting there.

EDIT:

for the first row,
we have total ethnicities as 8

```
3 GreaterEuropean
1 British
2 WestEuropean
1 French
1 nordic
```

so the score will be

1- [(3/8)^2 + (1/8)^2 + (2/8)^2 + (1/8)^2  + (1/8)^2]

Comment: Could we see the expected output for the above data.

Comment: @Dark I edited it, I hope it is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of numpy vectorization here i.e

```
one = df.drop(['total_ethnicities'],1).values
# Select the values other than total_ethnicities
two = df['total_ethnicities'].values[:,None]
# Select the values of total_ethnicities
df['diversity'] = 1 - pd.np.sum((one/two)**2, axis=1)
# Divide the values of one by two, square them. Sum over the axis. Then subtract from 1. 
df['diversity']

tconst
tt0000001    0.750000
tt0000002    0.666667
tt0000003    0.710744
tt0000004    0.666667
tt0000005    0.693878
Name: diversity, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I am getting this
ZeroDivisionError: long division or modulo by zero

Comment: Are you using python 2??

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
df2 = df.set_index('tconst')
total = df2.pop('total_ethnicities')
result = 1 - ((df2** 2 ).div(total**2, axis=0)).sum(axis=1)
result.name = 'gini'
```

> ```
> tconst
> tt0000001    0.750000
> tt0000002    0.666667
> tt0000003    0.710744
> tt0000004    0.666667
> tt0000005    0.693878
> Name: gini, dtype: float64
> ```

Apart from that, I always try to keep my raw data separate from my parsed data, so I would keep the columns `total_etnicities` in a separate series, and only when needed for the reporting of the results would I combine them

If you really want this result as an extra column in `df`, you can do this by:

```
df = df.join(result, on='tconst')
```

Comment: getting NaN in all values , if put the last line to df["diversity"]

Comment: did it using .values and equating to column

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to compare all columns to a given one, because the Gini Coefficient defines the difference in distributions. You will generate a Gini coefficient comparing distributions, for instance Italian,French,Jewish. Then, comparing to a given column you can even group these ethnicities in clusters of similar distributions.

Suppose df2 is your data frame. Gini Index formula is:

[image]

You select the pivot column (place_y) in Pandas:

```
place_y=df2.columns.get_loc("price_doc")

gini=[]
for i in range(0,df2.shape[1]):
    gini.append((df2.shape[0]+1-2*(np.sum((df2.shape[0]+1-df2.ix[:,i])*df2.ix[:,place_y])/np.sum(df2.ix[:,place_y])))/df2.shape[0])
```

Then you select the columns that best match your threshold, let's suppose 0.2, the most similar distributions:

```
np.where(np.array(np.abs(gini))<.2)[0]
```

In you case, it seems you want to compare examples (rows) and not features (columns) in order to generate a new column. That's the same rationality, transposed. In your pivot row Gini coefficient will be zero and all the others will have their coefficients.